# How to access parent component in angularjs 1.5

Tags: angularjs, components, angular-components

Hi i am trying to display simple components in angularjs where child needs to access parent name.And my code goes like this:

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='angular.min-1.5.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="componentApp">
    <div ng-controller="helloCnt"> 
        <hello name="Parent"></hello>
        <hello1 name="Child"></hello1>  
        <label>List: <input name="namesInput" ng-model="names" ng-list=" | "   required></label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE:

```
app.component('hello', {
        transclude: true,
        template:'<p>Hello I am {{$ctrl.name}} and ctrl name is {{myName}}</p>',
        bindings: { name: '@' },
        controller: function($scope) {
                        $scope.myName = 'Alain';
                        alert(1);
        }
});

app.component('hello1', {
        require: {
            parent: 'hello'
        },
        template:'<p>Hello I am {{$ctrl.name}} && my parent is {{myNameFromParent}} </p>',
        bindings: { name: '@' },
        controller: function($scope) {
                        $scope.myNameFromParent=this.parent.myName;
                        alert(2);
        }
});
```

And it throws an error :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'myName' of undefined`

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in the code and why it can't find the parent.Any inputs on the mistake I am making.Seems to be a small one I might have missed.

Comment: hello and hello1 are sibling scope, once check that!

Comment: I think something wrong with your component structure. A component should know nothing about the parent component. This is the best practice of component design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To inherit with require, the components need to be nested:

```
<hello name="Parent"></hello>
<hello1 name="Child"></hello1>
```

instead do

```
<hello name="Parent">
    <hello1 name="Child"></hello1>
</hello>
```

Then you can require the parent like so:

```
require: {
    parent: '^^hello'
  },
```

Comment: hi.could you also explain what is the difference between using '^' and '^^' while inheriting parent in require property?

Comment: @AmbarBhatnagar with ^ you access a parent an local controller and ^^ just the parent.

Comment: @not quite got it.

Answer (score 6):

Actually I got the answer after making following modification with the answer @gyc pointed:

JS CODE:

```
angular
    .module('componentApp', [])
    .controller('helloCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.names = ['morpheus', 'neo', 'trinity'];
    })
    .component('hello', {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<p>Hello I am {{parentCtrl.name}} and my name is {{parentCtrl.myName}}</p><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.myName = 'Braid';
        },
        bindings: {
            name: '@'
        }
    })
    .component('hello1', {
        template: '<p>Hello I am {{$ctrl.name}} && my parent is {{myNameFromParent}}  </p>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.$onInit = function () {
                $scope.myNameFromParent = this.parent.myName;
            };

        },
        bindings: {
            name: '@'
        },
        require: {
            parent: '^hello'
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="componentApp">
    <div ng-controller="helloCtrl">
        <hello name="Parent">
            <hello1 name="Child"></hello1>
        </hello>
        <label>List:
            <input name="namesInput" ng-model="names" ng-list=" | " required>
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The common mistake I was doing it was not following the nested component format and not using transclude in my parent. The rest worked fine when I made these two changes and modified my subsequent code.

P.S - The ng-list included in HTML has nothing to do with components.That was for other purpose.

@gyc - thanks for the help.Your input helped.

@daan.desmedt - I was hoping for the solution in components not directives.